# Laptop crashes due to nvlddmkm.sys when left alone

Tags: windows-7, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

Everything is fine when I am using the computer but if I leave it alone, it will (not 100% reproducible) give bsod. This is what whocrashed gives:

```
On Mon 17-Aug-15 05:08:39 GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\081715-16957-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: nvlddmkm.sys (nvlddmkm+0x36E0B3) 
Bugcheck code: 0x1000007E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000005, 0xFFFFF88004C120B3, 0xFFFFF880033CBC98, 0xFFFFF880033CB4F0)
Error: SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M
file path: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\nvlddmkm.sys
product: NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 355.60 
company: NVIDIA Corporation
description: NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 355.60 
Bug check description: This indicates that a system thread generated an exception which the error handler did not catch.
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
A third party driver was identified as the probable root cause of this system error. It is suggested you look for an update for the following driver: nvlddmkm.sys (NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 355.60 , NVIDIA Corporation). 
Google query: NVIDIA Corporation SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M
```

I have installed the latest driver. The gpu is gt950M

Comment: There are some resources on the internet (like http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/364825-laptop-bsod-nvlddmkm-sys.html). What have you tried?

Comment: I added registry entries to nvidia folder called tdrdelay and have it decimal32. I erased all nvidia drivers using driver fusion in safe mode, and reinstalled latest driver.